# Replace random string starting and ending using shell command

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

Appreciate any help to find out the solution for below scenario.

Input:

```
:50Kfoobar:53B:53B:53Bbaz:53B:53B;:50Kvoocar:53B:53B:53Bbaz:53B:53B
```

Output:

```
:50KCREDIT:53B:53B:53Bbaz:53B:53B;:50KCREDIT:53B:53B:53Bbaz:53B:53B
```

Tried using below command

```
sed 's/:50K.*:53B/:50KCREDIT:53B/g' <<<':50Kfoobar:53B:53B:53Bbaz:53B:53B;:50Kvoocar:53B:53B:53Bbaz:53B:53B'

producing below result
:50KCREDIT:53B
```

Comment: Use: `sed 's/:50K[^:]*:53B/:50KCREDIT:53B/'`

Comment: Explanation of @anubhava's suggestion: your `.*` is *greedy*, and will match **everything** up to the last 538.  The `[^:]*:` makes the match stop at each colon.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava and tink for your time and help.

Comment: FYI please!! attached dupe could be taken as a reference but doesn't look like an exact dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
awk '{gsub(/:50K[^:]*:53B/,":50KCREDIT:53B")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** using regex `:50K[^:]*:53B` which will match :50K till next occurrence of `:`(non-greedy match) then matching : followed by 53B, then replacing this matched part with :50KCREDIT:53B globally, finally printing the current line.

Comment: Thanks Ravinder for your time and help.